# Changing a dropdown based on another one

Tags: nodes, entities

I've got a content type with a dropdown with some states. And I've got another list (radio buttons) which should change the dropdown based on the selected item. Is that somehow possible?

I've tried Conditional Fields, but that didn't do what I want. Maybe rules? I'm kind of newbie with Drupal.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the dropdown ? Changing the options in it or displaying an other dropdown ?

Comment: Lets say I have a dropdown with options "opened, closed, progress" and another one with "1, 2, 3". If I select any option on the second dropdown, the first should automatically change to "progress".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this hardcoded, you might try to use the #ajax property of the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax)

You can reload your second dropdown on change of the value of the first dropdown and change the value while reloading the form.

I made a little example to give you an idea :

```
$form['number'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select Number'),
  '#options' => array(
      0 => 1,
      1 => 2,
      2 => 3,
  ),
  '#default_value' => 0,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_replace_dropdown_default_value_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'wrapper-dropdown',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
  ),
);

$default_value = !empty($form_state['values']['number']) ? $form_state['values']['number'] : 0;

$form['open_closed'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Open / Closed ?'),
  '#options' => array(
      0 => t('Open'),
      1 => t('Closed'),
      2 => t('Progress'),
  ),
  '#value' => $default_value,
  '#prefix' => '<div id="wrapper-dropdown">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

function ajax_replace_dropdown_default_value_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['open_closed'];
}
```

In your case you will have to do it in a `hook_form_alter` and add the `#ajax property` to your first dropdown and add prefix and suffix to give the second dropdown the proper value.

You can also check this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/752056) about AJAX with the FORM API :

Comment: No problem, glad to know that this was what you were looking for ;-)

Comment: Hello if this answer was good, can you mark it as one ? Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've used a module before called [Reference Option Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit). Basically you setup 2 fields as taxonomy term references (each with it's own taxonomy vocabulary), and then on each element of the second dropdown, you select which parent item it should show for. The only issue I ever had with it was it didn't always work for anonymous users if caching was enabled.